# curly braces and subshell

Tags: bash, subshell

I can't figure it out. As I read in documentaion, `{}` doesn't create a subshell. However, looks like that sometimes it does:

```
  $ unset T; echo "T_bfr=$T"; echo $$; { echo $$; export T=1; }; echo "T_afr=$T"
T_bfr=
4874
4874
T_afr=1

 $ unset T; echo "T_bfr=$T"; echo $$; { echo $$; export T=1 ; }|cat; echo "T_afr=$T"
T_bfr=
4874
4874
T_afr=
```

What is the difference? Why T is missing in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second case is different because that pipe runs in a subshell, where `T_aft=$T` is unset.

Comment: But why pipe with subshell wipes variable from curly braces?

Comment: Good question. The short answer is that the subshell is unaware of the newly set variable. Long answer - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes

Comment: You may wish to expand your answer with the comment you've given.

Comment: See [BashFAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) about pipes, subshells, and shell variables.